# Сколько времени ajax запрос ждет ответа от сервера?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Сколько времени .ajax метод ждет ответ? В моем примере он обращается к сервлету, и если в сервлете перед отправкой ответа добавить хотя бы секунду `Thread.sleep()`, то вызывается обработчик ошибки `error`, если его убрать, то ответ обрабатывается корректно. Просто в более сложном примере, когда сервлет уже в свою очередь к серверу обращается, что тоже занимает время, ответ опять-таки не приходит. Если вообще понятие времени ожидания запросом ответа?

Вот код `ajax` запроса

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login-button").click(function () {
            var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
            var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {login: userLogin, password: userPassword},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Successful request! Data is " + data.toString());
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Метод `service` в сервлете

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Даже если на секунду включить, ответ не проходит
    /*try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }*/


    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().print("test");

}
```

Comment: Наверное столько же, сколько браузер пытается открыть недоступные страницы. Или сколько сами укажите в параметре timeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала стоит убедиться, что возврат ajax-запроса происходит из-за нехватки времени - для этого проверяем статус ответа:

```
error: function(jqXHR, status, e) {
        if (status === "timeout") {  
            alert("Время ожидания ответа истекло!");
        } else {
            alert(status); // Другая ошибка
        }
}
```

Если все же ошибка связана с timeout, то можно вручную [установить](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) нужное значение, явно указав значение ожидания в миллисекундах:

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override
>   any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts
>   at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in
>   progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible
>   for a request to time out before it can be sent.

Стандартное значение timeout зависит от конкретной реализации браузера, судя по [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148830/what-is-jquerys-ajax-default-timeout-value) на enSO.